# Issue writing to Excel file using C++

Tags: c++, excel

We have a requirement to parse a file and write the data to an excel file using C++. I did a search and able to find a project which serves my purpose. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelFormat.aspx

Please find a few lines of code below where exactly the errors occur.

```
typedef std::ctype CT;  
CT const& ct = std::_USE(std::locale(), CT);  
ct.widen(&str[0], &*str.begin()+str.size(), &ret[0]);
```

The above functions (eg. _USE) seem to be related to VC++. Can somebody please let me know what exactly the above piece of code does?  and how to implement the same in native C++ functions?

Please let me know if any other information is needed...

Thanks!!

Comment: what error occurs exactly? what compiler are you using?
The standard functions are probably contained in the <locale> header, maybe use_facet can help you.

Comment: I found the definition of _USE as mentioned above and read about locale, facet., but couldn't get much out of it. Forgot to mention that we are compiling this with xcode. So issue is with vc++ functions like _USE(not sure though). I have tried including the locale header, but of no luck. The 3 lines of code I pasted actually converts a 'string' type to 'wstring' type. Any insight on this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried using 'use_facet' but of no help. Thanks!!

Comment: Is it a delimited file you are trying to parse and load into excel? Something like a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without further information. In any case I would try

```
CT const & ct = std::use_facet<CT>( std::locale() );
```

Comment: what happened exactly? did you try the line I wrote? did you get the same error you were having before?

Comment: I have already tried this earlier but the same error repeated. Probably I would have to check again and let you know how it goes. Thanks!!!

Comment: let me know. I added std:: before use_facet, to be consistent with std::locale.

Comment: I think I have taken care of the namespace while using 'use_facet' anyways, I would give one more try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: It worked like a magic!! Namespace seems to have done the trick. Thanks Francesco!!!! HAppy New Yr!!!

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, that segment of code is reformatting the string based on your computer's preferences for character arrays.

This line creates a C locale facet that contains said preferences. std::locale() is what actually specifies those preferences, and as far as I can tell, the second input specifies what the output type of the _USE function is.

```
std::ctype const& ct = std::_USE(std::locale(), std::ctype);
```

The second line uses the newly created C locale facet to reformat the c++ string str to a c style string (a char array) ret.

```
ct.widen(&str[0], &*str.begin()+str.size(), &ret[0]);
```

The most simple way of cutting this down that I can think of is:

```
char ret[str.size()];
strncpy(ret, str.c_str(), str.size());
```

However, that eliminates all of your locale formatting, which, depending on what is happening after word, could or could not be a problem.

If you want to keep the locale, then instead of using the _USE function, try looking into the ctype constructors. Specifically:

```
ctype(c_locale cloc, const mask *table, bool del, size_t refs)
```